# Normalizing Timestamps in Different formats to a common format

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, datetime-format

This might sound like a very naive question, but I am still curious about it.

So I have time stamp values in the following different formats :

1. Monday 17th of September 2012 08:20:32 AM CDT
2. Fri, 01 Feb 2013 12:55:59 GMT
3. 2015-04-07 13:39:21
4. Fri Sep 11 15:58:57 +0000 2015

Now, is there a way in Python to compare all of these different types of time stamps and may be like arrange them in a descending/ascending order ?

I was thinking of something like maybe normalize all of these time stamps to a common time stamp and then may be compare them. Will this make sense or is their a more efficient way of doing this ?

Comment: http://pytz.sourceforge.net/

Comment: and [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) using the **parser.parse** for fuzzy parsing

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. However, both of the above appear to be pretty vast libraries. Given that I am relatively new to these libraries and to python itself, I would really appreciate an example of how can I make use of these modules to achieve what is required.

Comment: convert the time strings into aware datetime objects (with fixed-offset `tzinfo`s): `dateutil.parser.parse(time_string)`. After that you could compare the objects directly. Note: your input (#1, #3) is ambiguous i.e., you may get inaccurate results in the general case if you don't provide more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments have already answered your question. But just posting an example to get you solve this. parser.parse from dateutil is used for getting datetime objects by fuzzy parsing of strings.

```
>>> import dateutil
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> datestrs = ['Monday 17th of September 2012 08:20:32 AM CDT', 'Fri, 01 Feb 2013 12:55:59 GMT', '2015-04-07 13:39:21', 'Fri Sep 11 15:58:57 +0000 2015']
>>> datetime_objs = []
>>> for datestr in datestrs:
...   datetime_objs.append(parser.parse(datestr))
... 
>>> datetime_objs
[datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 17, 8, 20, 32), datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 1, 12, 55, 59, tzinfo=tzutc()), datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 7, 13, 39, 21), datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 11, 15, 58, 57, tzinfo=tzutc())]
```

You finally have an array of datetime objects. You can carry on with other operations like comparing to arrange the way you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This was really helpful

Comment: Pleasure is mine :) . Now when you are into this, check the `dateutil` library and its usage.

Comment: @geek_ji: as [I said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32538284/normalizing-timestamps-in-different-formats-to-a-common-format#comment52934900_32538284), you can't compare naive datetime objects with timezone-aware datetime objects i.e., for a proper comparison you need additional info for cases #1, #3.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yes you are right. This needs to be done.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian and Barun thanks guys. I understand things a little better now. Appreciate all the pointers and support!